# Solidworks - how to make a groove on a double curvature surface

Tags: design, modeling, solidworks, cad

Today, as I was making -for another post - the following part

[image]

Although, I managed to use a couple of ways to do the above (revolve a sketch, and b) using swept cut) I wondered how would I make grooves easily on a double curvature surface, e.g.

Something like :

|  | double curvature |
| --- | --- |
| cymbal like | [image] |
| dome | [image] |

(I don't know if there will be a difference, but the dome seems simpler somehow).

I would like to see how that would be done:

- along an axis of symmetry (Seems to me simpler)
- along an offset

|  | Axis of symmetry | Offset to axis of symmetry |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | [image] | [image] |

Comment: I assume, it's a requirement for the 'groove' to be normal to the surface?

Comment: not really. (for the double curvature that might be a bit too difficult. even parallel would be fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholder answer - I've made the model, but don't have time to write up how I did it just now! :)

In short - make a plane, use intersection curve to make your sweep path. The, if you want to keep normal constant, make another path to use as a guide curve.

[image: Placeholder]

Comment: LH is constant normal, RH is vertical